# PHP: Mark as link values inside a string (a textarea string)

Tags: php, string, function

I'm developing a wikipedia-like Web application.
I want to show articles with the possibllity to link to other articles.

The way to do it that I can think of, is to mark manually values as a sign for link, like this: " Hello |world| " ("world" would be the link for an article). later, i'll have to find inside the textarea string all the words marked with | on start and | on it's end. bottom line, some string functions are needed.

How should I do that? can you, please, give me an example?

Thank you in advance.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Instead of trying to create your own pseudo code for embedding links into plain text, just use an already established system: Markdown.

Markdown is simple and easy to learn and there are many libraries for PHP parsing markdown (eg https://github.com/erusev/parsedown). Using this library your example would be:

```
$Parsedown = new Parsedown();

echo $Parsedown->text('Hello [world](https://somelink.com)');
```

Comment: Thank you! how should I use it for multiple words?

Comment: anything inside the brackets will be a link, so your link could be `[this is a link](https://somelink.com)`. There are lots of markdown guides available for reference, eg https://www.markdownguide.org/cheat-sheet/